# Definir a primeira página a ser carregada pelo navegador

Tags: php, html, servidor

Eu estou construindo uma CMS e tenho 2 ficheiros:

- o index.php
- o index.php (que está alojado na pasta themes/original).

É possível fazer com que o navegador carregue o ficheiro index.php (na pasta themes/original) antes de carregar o index.php?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode definir uma regra no arquivo `.htaccess` do seu server

Exemplo:

```
DirectoryIndex themes/original/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer simplesmente carregar o conteúdo ou executar algum script que esteja em themes/original/index.php, utilize include_once('themes/original/index.php);

Segue documentação do método: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include-once.php